# What's going on with the "Marshal" badge?

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, badges

I've just been awarded the Marshal gold badge twice. In 5 minutes.

**A)** I was under the impression this was a "one time only" badge

**B)** I'm not the only one who just randomly got it. [22 others](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/71/marshal) seems to have received one or two of these badges in the past few minutes.

[image]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/somethings-wrong-with-excavating-and-some-other-badges-too

Answer (score 2):

Oops. Looks like someone at SE Towers pressed the wrong button/s.

### [Excavator and Marshall badges are being awarded over and over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/280023/excavator-and-marshall-badges-are-being-awarded-over-and-over)

> We just did a major revamp of how badges are awarded behind the scenes
> to drastically reduce the load on SQL Server. It now takes advantage
> of some pre-compute work we're doing to track badge progress in the
> profile.
>
> **However, I screwed up 2 queries, specifically the text names of the
> badges that prevent duplicate awarding.** I was thinking to myself
> earlier "hey, maybe we should pass these in" as part of the rewrite -
> but it's not quite so simple. I'll take another look at this soon but
> when we're not fighting fires from a SQL Server upgrade. The
> cardinality changes which hosed some of the bigger badge queries
> needed urgent attention here, which ended up as a major revamp and
> introduced the 2 errors reported here.
>
> Apologies for all the bad grants here - that certainly wasn't the
> intention. Due to how badges get tested, it's also not a symptom that
> shows up locally. If I can change this to a param exclusion passed by
> the code then things like this become far less likely to happen going
> forward.
>
> **Nick Craver♦**

Fixed now, all apart from the fact that my badge count still says

[image]

which I gather will get fixed overnight

> I have cleaned up all achievements and grants associated with the bad
> code. User badge counts (on user cards and flair) will sync up tonight
> as part of a regular process.

Comment: @armadillo - I still have the notifications. I reckon they're gonna stay for the time being.

Comment: "However, I screwed up 2 queries" - I'm glad to see that people doing that aren't confined to my workplace :)

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - I guess we should be glad that they're making websites, not flight-control software.